# React Native: State changed, component doesnt re-render

Tags: react-native

After image is selected through Image Picker the button which opens the picker has to be replaced by the Image. I am doing that in the following manner

```
{ this.state.userImage === null ?  
        <IconButton  
          icon={{name: "photo-camera", size: 32}}
          buttonStyle={{backgroundColor: "#397af8", borderRadius: 2,marginLeft: 50,height: 50, width: 200}}
          textStyle={{textAlign: 'center',color: "#000000"}}
          title={this.state.textBttn}
          onPress={() => this._selectImage()}/> : <Image style={styles.userimg} source={this.state.userImage} />
          }
```

Am able to confirm that the userImage changes after an image is selected but the component doesn't re render. Any solutions please?

Edit : updating the state

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, (response) => {
  console.log('Response = ', response);

  if (response.didCancel) {
    console.log('User cancelled image picker');
  }
  else if (response.error) {
    console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
  }
  else {
    let source = { uri: response.uri };

    // let source = { uri: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + response.data };

    this.setState({
      userImage: source,
      testVal : 'changed'

      });
  console.log("state = "+this.state.userImage);
  console.log("state = "+this.state.testVal);
  }
});
```

Comment: what is the value of `this.state.userImage`?

Comment: initially it's null, after image selection it changes to the source of the selected image @bennygenel

Comment: whats the source? It has to be an object in form of `{ uri: '/path/to/remote/image'}` or `require('/path/to/local/image')`

Comment: I get the source in the following manner
`source = { uri: response.uri } `, response is the object returned by the Image Picker.

Comment: can you add the part where you set the userImage from the response you get Image Picker

Comment: have edited the post, have to mention that this view is under a Transition View and when I come back to this view the icon button is correctly replaced by the selected image.

Comment: This seems like it might be styling issue. To eliminate that please set your userImage value to a some dummy image from web manually and see if it shows up.

Comment: this view is under a Transition View and when I come back to this view the IconButton is correctly replaced by the selected image, so don't think it's a styling issue

Comment: I'm sorry I have no idea. Your code looks just fine to me.

Comment: yeah it's been bugging me since yesterday, thanks anyways

Comment: Some things I would check: if you hardcode your state with the same value that your `response.uri` returns, does it work? Are your components sharing the same `this.state`? What else your `_selectImage()` contains?

Comment: @soutot I was able to partially figure out the issue. I am using the react-native-transition library and this whole view is wrapped in a Transition View. When the Transition wrap is removed then it works perfectly. Have opened an issue already, any help will be appreciated.